# ionic 2 - Get window.scrollTop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

How can I do this in Ionic without jquery?

```
  var window_top = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + 56;
  var div_top = jQuery('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
```

Comment: Where you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @sebaferreras no i wasn't i ended up using jquery like that

Answer (score 6):

You can use a reference to the [`Content`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/content/Content/):

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage{
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  scrollToTop() {
    this.content.scrollToTop();
  }

  scrollTo(elementId:string) {
    let yOffset = document.getElementById(elementId).offsetTop;
    this.content.scrollTo(0, yOffset, 4000)
  }
}
```

There are a lot of properties that you can use; one of the most importants is...

`getContentDimensions()`: Returns the content and scroll elements’ dimensions.

```
Property                    Type    Details
dimensions.contentHeight    number  content offsetHeight
dimensions.contentTop       number  content offsetTop
dimensions.contentBottom    number  content offsetTop+offsetHeight
dimensions.contentWidth     number  content offsetWidth
dimensions.contentLeft      number  content offsetLeft
dimensions.contentRight     number  content offsetLeft + offsetWidth
dimensions.scrollHeight     number  scroll scrollHeight
dimensions.scrollTop        number  scroll scrollTop
dimensions.scrollBottom     number  scroll scrollTop + scrollHeight
dimensions.scrollWidth      number  scroll scrollWidth
dimensions.scrollLeft       number  scroll scrollLeft
dimensions.scrollRight      number  scroll scrollLeft + scrollWidth
```